# Anyway to open/close memcached server in java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, memcached

So I've got a little REST API I've developed that incorporates a cache to cache data from a database for efficiency purposes. As it now stands, I have to start up the server separately from command line, and then run my web application. When I terminate my web application I then  have to go back to command line and close the server there as well. Is there anyway to start the memcached server automatically (like with code) when I start my java application and/or close it when I terminate it?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer doing it from java code, you could use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to invoke the memcache startup/shutdown script(code example from javadoc):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
env.remove("OTHERVAR");
env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

And you need to implement a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to receive servlet context lifecycle events, i.e. initialize & destroy.